# Adding AuthenticationManager to SecurityConfig with spring-security-web 6.1.5

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to create an application that has a `User` who can be assigned `Tasks`. I am using Spring Security to authenticate the application. For the sake of avoiding confusion, I have renamed my SpringSecurity user table as `app_users`.

1. My `users` table and `app_users` are different. My `users` table just stores a mapping of task <---> user data. `app_users` is the sprint security table
2. I am confused about AuthManagers/UserDetailsService/SecurityConfig thing.

   - what i want to do is - my `users` table won't have any rows. There is going to be only one user `admin` in `app_users` and users that will have `ROLE_ADMIN` permission.
   - So, using this `admin` user I would try to create users - `api/v1/signup` POST
3. I am having trouble configuring the `AuthenticationManager`. The `SecurityConfig` looks like so -

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtProvider;

    @Autowired
    protected SecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService, JwtTokenProvider jwtProvider) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.jwtProvider = jwtProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/signup").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers("/api/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return auth.build();
    }

}
```

The `AuthenticationManager configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` has been deprecated. How do we configure the AuthManager with `spring-security-web 6.1.5`?

---

---

This is my GitHub repository - https://github.com/yadavvi91/taskscheduler

Feel free to give any other comments on the project and its design.

**TLDR** about my project -

- dockercompose.yml for postgres+redis+springbootapp
- openapi.yml for contract first development
- flyway scripts for tables users, tasks, task_status
- SecurityConfig for JWT token based authentication. The tokens are stored in Redis. They don't have much information other than that they are sent in the JWT format.

Comment: Does this [commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/bea2b4676e6bd4b34269385859baea4421a545c8) answer to your question ?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, try:

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    var provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

    return new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);
}
```

Another possibility (the one I have used successfully, after reading https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-auth-providers):

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager configure(HttpSecurity http,
                                       PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) throws Exception {
    return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
               .userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
               .build();
}
```